# Div tag at the same height

Tags: css, html

I have 3 divs which I want them to display at the same height left center and right but that isnt happening right now.

Proof of concept:
 https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51736887/Untitled.png (must have 10 rep to post images ughh)

The problem is that the sidebars and the main content are the one bellow the other and stuck to the side not just under the navbar like I want them.
Image of what happens: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51736887/Untitled%20-%20Copy.png

This is my current code(includes only 1 of the 2 sidebars):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="stylesheets/public.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body>
    <h3 align="center"><img src="afterlogo.png" alt="" height="358" width="339"></h3>

<div id="nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/public/forums/">Forums</a></li>
    <li><a href="/public/donate.php">Donations</a></li>
    <li><a href="/vote">Vote</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="content">
<p><b> test </b> 0000-00-00 00:00:00<br><b> test 2 </b> 0000-00-00 00:00:00<br>test3     0000-00-00 00:00:00<br>test4 0000-00-00 00:00:00<br>test <br />test <br />test <br />test     <br />test <br />test <br />test <br />test <br />test <br />test <br />    </p>
</div>
<div class="sidebar"> test </div>

<div class="footer">
&nbsp;
<br />
Test footer
<br />
&nbsp;
</div>
</html>
```

and heres the css:

```
body {
background-image:url('../bg.png');
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: bottom;
}

#nav a:link{
text-decoration: none;
color: #000000;
font-size: 2em;
}
#nav a:visited {
color:#000000;
}

#nav a:hover {
color: #00FF00;
}

#nav {
border-radius: 15px;
background-size: cover;
background: rgba(76, 92, 70, 0.7);
background-position: top;
text-align: center;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
margin:6em;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
word-spacing: 2em;
}

.nav {
text-decoration: none;
}

li {
display: inline;
}

.content {
border-radius: 15px;
background-size: cover;
/*background-image:url('../content.png');*/
background: rgba(76, 92, 70, 0.7);
background-position: top;
text-align: center;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
margin-left: auto ;
margin-right: auto ;
width: 500px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.sidebar {
border-radius: 15px;
/*background-size: cover;*/
background: rgba(76, 92, 70, 0.7);
background-position: top;
text-align: left;
overflow: hidden;
margin-left: 120px;
margin-right: auto;
width: 220px;
float: left;
}

.footer {
clear:both;
border-radius: 500px;
text-align: center;
background: rgba(76, 92, 70, 0.7);
background-position: top;
text-align: center;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
margin:6em;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: You may get more help if you post all relevant generated HTML code.

Comment: @SombreErmine ok added the entire html code ^

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking to achieve equal height columns - here's [an excellent writeup](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/) by Chris Coiyer detailing the different techniques you can use.

p/s: It would be good if you can include the actual HTML output of the final layout (not in separate PHP files) ;)

---

**Edit**: After having a look at your code, it seems that you are positioning the sidebar absolutely. Is there any reason why you are doing so? You could have easily floated the sidebar and the content, so they will sit side by side.

---

**Update**: First of all, you should avoid using deprecated HTML features, such as the `align="center"` property. You should delegate all attributes that dictate layout to your CSS file instead.

You cannot combine both `float` and `position: absolute` on the same element. They are conflicting properties, and both will take your element out of the normal document flow. What I would suggest is wrapping your content and sidebar in a common parent element, say, `<main>`, `<section>` or `<div>`, and them floating them.

Here's the revised markup:

```
<section class="main">
    <div class="content">
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">test</div>
</section>
```

And CSS:

```
.main {
    margin: 0 6em;
    /* or you can set width using "width: ..." */
    overflow: hidden; /* Prevent parent from collapsing */
}
.content, .sidebar {
    background-color: rgba(76, 92, 70, 0.7);
    border-radius: 15px;
    float: left;
}
    .content {

    }
    .sidebar {
        width: 250px;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2X7pv/

Comment: No actually thats not a problem, the problem is this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51736887/Untitled%20-%20Copy.png

Comment: @Nick Again, it's very difficult to see your final HTML output just by the files you have provided. Would you do us a big favour and combine them?

Comment: I combined the code into 1 code tag, and no not a specific reason the position was left there I was doing various tests to see if it would be positioned better. EDIT I updated the css code